# java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service (device specific)

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

Problem with my device "karbon sparkle v (android one )  version 6.0

When i try to open QR scanner :

```
//getting the camera permission for API 21 and above dynamically
        try {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(QRActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {


        }
        mQrCodeReaderView = (QRCodeReaderView) findViewById(R.id.qrdecoderview);
        mQrCodeReaderView.setOnQRCodeReadListener(this);
```

And for the first time only when app asks for Marshmallow Camera permission it crashes, and this is my device log. But it does not crash again if i grant the permission  but  it still keeps asking for permission each time i try to access the qr scanner.

This is my error log in logcat even though it doesn't seem like problem in my java file coz it does not give link to any of my java file from logcat.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.gurkhatech.schoolmanagement, PID: 32576
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
                                                                                         at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:495)
                                                                                         at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:341)
                                                                                         at com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.GingerbreadOpenCameraInterface.open(GingerbreadOpenCameraInterface.java:57)
                                                                                         at com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.CameraManager.openDriver(CameraManager.java:77)
                                                                                         at com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView.surfaceCreated(QRCodeReaderView.java:110)
                                                                                         at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:582)
                                                                                         at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:177)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2055)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is my Mainfest.xml camera usage permission and feature declaration :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

So

**1) any idea how to fix the fix the problem with crash in my specific 
device?**

**2) and how to fix app asking for permission each time rather than asking once and working without asking for rest of the runs in android ?**

Comment: Could you please fix your your log entry? We can see only the first line

Comment: please scroll to left , i could not fix the overflow issue of code format in this case sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if user granted the permission to access the camera before calling `startCamera()`. For example you can start doing something like this:

```
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      initQRCodeReaderView();
    } else {
      requestCameraPermission();
    }
```

and that two methods:

```
private void initQRCodeReaderView() {
    qrCodeReaderView = (QRCodeReaderView) content.findViewById(R.id.qrdecoderview);
    qrCodeReaderView.startCamera();
}

private void requestCameraPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DecoderActivity.this,
              new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA }, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA);
    } 
  }
```

You can check the sample project in the library samples if you want to see a working example of this.
https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView/tree/master/samples